# Spawn multiple children processes

Tags: c, process, exec, fork

So I want to spawn a number of children processes equal to a value inputted from the command line.  I have all the values and everything reading in just fine, I just need to figure out how to spawn these children, and have them all call the same program.

Here is what I have so far:

```
for(int i = 0; i < processes; i++)
{
    pid = fork();
    printf("%d\n", pid);
}

if(pid < 0)
{
perror("fork");
exit(-1);

}

else if(pid == 0)
{

    /*for(int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        execl("~/cs370/PA2/gambler.c","run", NULL);
        Gamble(percent);
    }*/

}
```

So to be clear again.  I want to spawn `"processes"` amount of children, that all call `"gambler.c"`.  But ONLY 5 can be running at a time.  It should `wait()`, and then process the rest of the children 5 at a time.

Sample input:

`run -p 60 10`

Where -p is a percentage to be fed to gambler.c which just returns success or failure based on a random number generator.  `60` is the percentage.  `10` is the number of processes.

Any help is much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the `exec` family?  `Exec` will spawn processes.  You can then use `wait` to monitor the processes.  `fork` will give you the PID and you can then have a second thread loop over each pid calling `wait` and keeping track of each active process.

[wait man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait)

[exec man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec)

```
pid_t pid = fork()
if (pID == 0)
{
     //child
     //immediatly call whichever exec you need.  Do not do anything else.
     //do not log a message or print a string.  Any calls to c++ standard strings
     //will risk deadlocking you.
}
else if (pid < 0)
{
   //error
} 
else
{
   //parent.  store pid for monitoring
}
```

Comment: When using exec, do I need to set `pid = fork()` as I did above? Or will exec automatically create all of these processes that I need?

Comment: Exec replaces the current process space.  So you still need to fork.

Comment: Duh... I forgot XP.  Okay.  So I call fork once, not in a loop.  However, if I call exec in a loop, will it give new pids each time? Or will it spam the same one "x" amount of times?

Comment: Each time you launch a process you will want to fork and then exec.

Comment: After the fork, you have to check if you are the parent or the child process.  The child process should then call exec and the parent continue doing what it does.

Comment: Okay. So all of that should be wrapped in a loop that keeps going until it's out of `"processes"` right?  And then I need something to ensure only 5 are running at a time using `wait()`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38197/discussion-between-mjr-and-necrode)